# React Class behaviour with "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why do I need to add `bind(this)` for `handleChange` in the `onChange` handler to have the proper `this` keyword?

```js
class SearchBar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  handleChange(){
    console.log(this)
    this.props.onUserInput(
      this.refs.filterTextInput.value,
      this.refs.inStockOnlyInput.checked
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Searrch...." 
          value={this.props.filterText}
          ref="filterTextInput"
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} // the bind(this) is needed if not this in handleChange became undefined
        />
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.props.inStockOnly}
            ref="inStockOnlyInput"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          {' '}
          only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because with the new React `extends Component` syntax, they removed autobinding for this on component creation like they had in the old `.createClass` syntax. By default, with the class syntax in es2015, you have to bind this to a method in order to use the class this, so the same holds here.

You can read about React's decision to make this change in [this changelog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) blog post.

Comment: then, this is the way is going to be, thanks so much for your answer!